# Using Python DAE solver for coupled equations in time and space

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, algebraic-data-types, scikits

I would like to solve two coupled equations in time and space, using the scikits.odes.dae solver.

My equations are as follows:

dy<sub>1</sub>/dt = dy<sub>1</sub>/dz + y<sub>2</sub>

y<sub>1</sub> = 5 * y<sub>2</sub>

The code I have written is the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scikits.odes import dae

N  = 51 #number os spacesteps
L  = 1.0 #[m] length of sorbent bed, also a guess 
dz = L/(N-1) #[m] length of space step

time = np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.1)
dydz = 1

y0 = [1, 0.2] #initial values y0[0] = y1 and y0[1] = y2
yp0 = [1, 1] #initial guess for \dot{y1} and \dot{y2}

def trial_space(t, y, ydot, result):
    result[0] = ydot[0] - 6 * dydz + y[1]
    result[1] = y[0] - 5 * y[1]

solver = dae('ida', trial_space)
solution = = solver.solve(time, y0, yp0)
```

Currently, I am feeding the solver a constant value of dydz, but actually I would like to use a central differencing scheme to obtain
dy/dz[i] = (y[i+1] - y[i-1])/(2*dz)

How do I integrate this into the solver?

Comment: You might have gotten the wrong idea about the user interface. The DAE function should be designed to have to compute the residuals at one point x given the state vector y and and the tangent ydot at this point. Check the documentation and the use examples.

Comment: What is dydz? Is the equation a PDE with equation constraints? For a simple DAE there should only be one independent variable.

Comment: dydz is a PDE currently set to be a constant so that the code works. However, I would like to include the equation for central differencing above so that dy/dz is computed from the current values of y in space. If I were to be able to do this, I would change my initial conditions for y and ydot, such that they are arrays of initial values in space

Comment: A more general question would be is there a solver for complex DAEs?

Comment: What is complex, the y or $z$? Or do you mean that the y are functions to z and t, holomorphic in z? Otherwise the PDE would just have two real space dimensions. I'm unsure if there is a numerical solver for ODE or PDE over the complex plane. What would a solution look like, values on a grid, rectangular or radial, perhaps truncated power series expansions at the grid points? Or something like finite elements with holomorphic patches?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean complex numbers, I mean that y is a function of both z and t (z is real).

Comment: Then your original code is correct. You could announce that you transformed a PDE to a DAE system via method-of-lines. And you can eliminate the loop via numpy slice operations, `dydz[1:-1]=(y[2:]-y[:-2])/(2*dz)`, add the boundary values with forward and backward differentiation formulas.